# Google Fusion , Map Overlays and breaking out polyline via a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

My question is based on the following [example from Google](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/mouseover_map_styles). I have gotten it to work great to pull out my polygon shapes from my fusion table, similar to their shapes. My issue arises when I try and alter the script to pull out some polyline data I have. The issue is in the breaking down of the rows data array. The dataset for the correct polygons is as follows.

"rows": [
  [
   "129",
   {
    "geometry": {
     "type": "Polygon",
     "coordinates": [
      [
       [
        -86.3055326754,
        39.8143343479,
        0.0
       ],
       [
        -86.3056957826,
        39.8139995783,
        0.0
       ],
       [
        -86.3059116214,
        39.8137158473,
        0.0
       ],
       [
        -86.3055326754,
        39.8143343479,
        0.0
       ]
      ]
     ]
    }
   }
  ],etc....

The polylines is as follows
"rows": [
  [
   "1",
   {
    "geometry": {
     "type": "LineString",
     "coordinates": [
      [
       -86.2411593096,
       40.1368952707,
       0.0
      ],
      [
       -86.2413739094,
       40.1367194041,
       0.0
      ],
      [
       -86.241866376,
       40.1197924711,
       0.0
      ]
     ]
    }
   }
  ],etc..

The polygon has an extra [] that is throwing off my ability to parse through the data! It is driving me nuts! Serious points to answer this one! [Example of mine here](http://wrestore.iupui.edu/fusion/mapWatershedPolylinesTable.php). I just dont know enough about javascript arrays. Thanks

Comment: The line is an **array of points**, while the polygon is an **array of arrays of points**, because the polygon can be a multi-polygon, (like a territory with islands), and that's why the extra []. you just need to take that into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that only parses polylines:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_mouseover_map_styles_polylines.html

I couldn't find any documentation or description of the expected output (other than "GeoJSON"), it would be nice if there was a way to detect polygons vs. polylines vs. markers and parse them appropriately.

Here is a description of [GeoJSON](http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html)

Here is a page that parse [polylines](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linkto.html?lat=39.923549&lng=-86.306907&zoom=10&type=m&tableid=1im8RszWUjZZhZdBnO8C0rfWGvT059O2EKk6TvZs&tablequery=SELECT%20%20geometry,%20GRID_CODE%20FROM), [polygons](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linkto.html?lat=37.174668&lng=-38.845970&zoom=2&type=m&tableid=1foc3xO9DyfSIF6ofvN0kp2bxSfSeKog5FbdWdQ&tablequery=SELECT%20kml_4326,%20name%20FROM%20&where=name%20does%20not%20contain%20%27Antarctica%27) and [markers](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linkto.html?lat=14.620282&lng=-90.504716&zoom=12&type=m&tablequery=SELECT%20geometry,%20name,%20description%20FROM&tableid=1npi-QWwoZ6LP_9wwHiwiG2omzMm6R9Qoj5aMjkM) (not well tested).

Comment: Thanks geocodezip. I might be back to you shortly. Not sure I know what the bounds. is all about. Can you explain? This brings across a question about adapting this. I am going to have multiple datasets coming in (5) and then I need to put them out on the map. Some will be polygons, others lines, others markers. When they come in I need to group them so I can turn the visibility on and off for them. How can I put each result from a specific query into a array to turn the overlays on and off?

Comment: The bounds (on the [first example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_mouseover_map_styles_polylines.html) just centers and zooms the map to show all the polylines.  The [second example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_mouseover_map_styles_generic_JSON.html) was my first cut at a generic GeoJSON parser, to allow displaying polylines, polygons, and markers; as I said, it hasn't been tested with markers at all. Anything else should be another question (after you give it a go).

Comment: http://wrestore.iupui.edu/model/mapScriptTry.html So geocodezip, I have redone your script and gotten it to work on other pages but am now getting an error that the callback function is not defined. I am confused.   url.push('&callback=drawWet1');  when that runs it tells me that drawWet1 is not defined yet it is!

Comment: This should be another question (as this one has already been accepted and this is really another question).

Comment: Will do. I will post it as another. Agreed!